# How to do the Authorization in Asp.net by using Identity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

For doing authorization in asp.net mvc 5 I have searched lot on internet but not getting correct answer. Actually I am using Visual studio community edition with .net framework 4.5.2 and mvc5. I want to do the Authorization in my project. My project is created with no authentication mode while creating a project.

Firstly I have tried these things:

I typed a command "Enable Migrations" on Package manager console.
Then I got one error like: Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing DbCompiledModel.
I dont know how to resolve this error. please help me to get out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which approach did you chooses to build our database model? Code First, Model First or Database First?

I'm asking because you can't use migrations with Model First or Database First approach. EF Migrations is a product targeted for Code First approach. CodeFirst assumes that you will never make any changes manually to the database. All the changes to the database will go through the code first migrations.

But there is solution for that - you can use Code First approach with an existing database. Take a look here: [Using EF “Code First” with an Existing Database](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database#7579835).

Comment: I am using Database first approach. Firstly i have created database tables. Then created model classes by using entity framework. After that I was creating authorization with Enable Migrations command.

Comment: Thank you very much